# How do I select things behind/near the gizmo?

Tags: edit-mode, 3d-manipulator, select

I've looked everywhere but I can't find a way to select things "behind" the gizmo in 2.80. It's like there's a forcefield that gets in the way. I didn't have this problem in 2.7x. Is there some setting that allows me to select through the gizmo so I don't have to keep disabling it while editing?

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem and the solution is to go to

*Edit > Preferences > Keymap* then select *Drag* under *Activate Gizmo*.

and it should work.

Comment: Thank you... finally don't have to toggle the gizmo on/off to select things. You've saved me from thousands of extra clicks.